# Why I'm getting False?

Tags: python

I made a simple `print` function that just check if `4 * 5 = 20 is True`.

Why am I getting `False` ?

```
result = 20
Num1 = 4
Num2 = 5

print(Num1*Num2 == result is True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Num1*Num2 == result is True` is an example of operator chaining, and is equivalent to:

```
(Num1*Num2 == result) and (result is True)
```

This is similar to how `1 < x < 10` is equivalent to `1 < x and x < 10`. It happens because both `==` and `is` are considered comparison operators, and two comparison operators in sequence are chained in this manner.

Since `result is True` returns False, the overall result is false.

In general, you shouldn't write `x is True` - just write `x`. Here: `print(Num1*Num2 == result)`.

Answer (score 3):

Check:

```py
result = 20
Num1 = 4
Num2 = 5

print(Num1*Num2 == result is True)
#False
print((Num1*Num2 == result) is True)
#True
print((Num1*Num2) == (result is True))
#False
```

You could solve it by putting brackets in the right places.

Comment: Your examples are not equivalent to OP's code. What actually happens here is chaining of comparison operators.

Comment: Yup, you're right- I was wrong about symptoms, I was right about the cure though ;) this kind of proves your point: ```print(False==False is False) #True```